# Алгоритм набора слов на аналоговой клавиатуре телефона

Tags: java, алгоритм, структуры-данных

На собеседовании задали задачу: имеется клавиатура аналогового телефона от 0 до 9, где каждой цифре соответствуют три буквы, 1 - абв, 2 - где и т.д.
Необходимо написать реализацию набора слов по следующему принципу: при вводе цифр выводятся в качестве подсказки три слова, начинаются на соответствующие буквы. При вводе 1 - три слова а-, б-, в-, при вводе 1,2 - три слова аг-, бд-, ве-, и т.д.
Решить не смог, но до сих пор думаю на реализацией. Подскажите как это можно реализовать, например на java и какую структуру данных использовать. Напрашивается дерево, но не знаю как реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим в базе хранятся имена абонентов, типа:

1. Иванов
2. Петров
3. Сидоров

Каждой букве в имени сопоставляем число, в соответствии с наборной клавиатурой (диском), в итоге получим:

1. 422652 (Иванов)
2. 536652 (Петров)
3. 6435652 (Сидоров)

Остальное уже дело техники. При наборе цифры 4 - смотрим на массив цифр и понимаем, что с 4-ки начинается только Иванов.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала на 10 кнопках расположить 33 буквы на каждой по 3 не получится, поэтому либо нужно 11 кнопок, либо на каких-то кнопках будет по 4 буквы. Поскольку 3 слова то легче первый вариант.

Например так

```
     char[][] buttons = {
        {'ъ','ы','ь'},
        {'а','б','в'},
        {'г','д','е'},
        {'ё','ж','з'},
        {'и','й','к'},
        {'л','м','н'},
        {'о','п','р'},
        {'с','т','у'},
        {'ф','х','ц'},
        {'ч','ш','щ'},
        {'э','ю','я'}
    };
```

А дальше все просто, индекс слова это индекс символа во вложенном массиве, а индекс главного массива индекс кнопки. Последовательность набранных кнопок формирует три начала слова, а после этого например в базе ищутся по одному слову начинающиеся на каждое сочетание.
Например последовательное нажатие клавиш: 5 1  выведет три сочетания начала слов: ла, мб, нв. Дальше формируется например запрос в БД (все зависит от того, где хранятся слова).

Answer (score 0):

```js
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Индекс элемента массива words соответствует кнопке номеронабирателя телефона
        String[] words = {"", "", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"};
        String[] lines = {"", "", "", ""};
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String r = "", t = "";
        int n, m;
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {   // предполагается 7-значный телефонный номер
            do {
                System.out.println("Введите число (0..9):");
                r = reader.readLine();
            } while (r.length() == 0 || r.length() > 1 || (r.length() == 1 && (r.charAt(0) > '9' || r.charAt(0) < '0')));
            n = Integer.parseInt(r);
            if (k == 6)
                r = "";
            else
                r = "-";
            String s = words[n];
            if (n > 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    lines[i] = lines[i].concat(String.format("%c", s.charAt(i)));
                    System.out.println(lines[i] + r);
                }
                if (lines[3].length() > 0 && s.length() == 3)
                    System.out.println(lines[3] + r);
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    lines[i] = lines[i].concat(String.format("%d", n));
                    System.out.println(lines[i] + r);
                }
                if (lines[3].length() > 0) {
                    lines[3] = lines[3].concat(String.format("%d", n));
                    System.out.println(lines[3] + r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В программе используется американский стандарт расположения букв латиницы на кнопках номеронабирателя телефонного аппарата. В СССР до 1968 года существовала практика наряду с цифрами использовать символы кириллицы на кнопочном номеронабирателе, но стандарта по их размещению не было принято. Кнопки "0" и "1" как в американском, так и в отечественном вариантах размещения оставались свободными от букв. Пример: 0-"", 1-"", 2-"абвг", 3-"дежз", 4-"ийкл", 5-"мноп", 6-"рсту", 7-"фхцч", 8-"шщъы", 9-"ьэюя".